# C - if statement is being ignored

Tags: c

h_array[i] is less than 19 for the first few cases. However, it still prints k as 0. Could someone help me out as to why this happens?

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int j = h_array[i];
    int k = 0;
    if (h_array[i]<19) {
      int k = 20 - j;
    }
    int l = 20;
    while (l>=k) {
      printf ("%d - %d\n\n\n",l,k);
      l--;
    }
  }
```

Comment: We need enough code to replicate the problem.

Comment: `int k = 20 - j;` should be `k = 20 - j;`

Comment: @IłyaBursov that worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is you've re-declared 'k' inside the body of the if statement.  The compiler will usually generate a warning about this.

In this case the 'k' variable with the scope of the condition body is modified, whilst the 'k' in the parent scope retains its original value (0).

Removing the type specifier should fix the issue.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int j = h_array[i];
    int k = 0;
    if (h_array[i]<19) {
      k = 20 - j;
    }
    int l = 20;
    while (l>=k) {
      printf ("%d - %d\n\n\n",l,k);
      l--;
    }
  }
```

Comment: @coderx123 Lesson learned (hopefully): Raise your compiler's warning level to the maximum and handle each of the warnings and errors.

Answer (score 1):

Its because of the scope visibility of the variable `int k`

Your code has 2 `int k`. An outer `k` and an inner `k`. When the `k` inside the if statement goes out of scope, the value being printed is the value of the outer `k`, which in this case is `0`.

The correct solution would be:

```
k = 20 - j;
```

Not :

```
int k = 20 - j;
```